# Php to calculate marks and award grades

Tags: php, mysql

Just wondering what is the problem with my below php, I am trying to insert into two tables marks and results. For the first type of exams I want it to be inserted in the two tables. Second type of exams to be inserted to marks and then update results table, that is to take the marks of the previous exams and add together the assign grade. When I post the first marks, it goes well. Now the second marks is the there is problem; marks table will be inserted successfully but updating results table gives different results, result column either become 0 or 1, and grade remains the same. Can anyone study my codes below and tell me where there is problem please or any other way to do this! I will appreciated. Thank you.

```
<?php

    include('../database/dbcon.php');

        $tearcher_post_id = $_POST['tearcher_id'];
        $year_id = $_POST['year_id'];
        $term_id = $_POST['term_id'];
        $subject_post_code = $_POST['subject_code'];
        $student_no = $_POST['student_no'];
        $exam_id = $_POST['exam_id'];
        $class_id = $_POST['class_id'];
        $marks = $_POST['marks'];

        $grade = '';
        if($marks >=0 && $marks<= 19){
                $grade = 'E';
            }else if($marks > 19 && $marks <= 29){
                $grade = 'D-';
            }else if($marks > 29 && $marks <=34){
                $grade = 'D';
            }else if($marks > 34 && $marks <=39){
                $grade = 'D+';
            }else if($marks > 39 && $marks <=44){
                $grade = 'C-';
            }else if($marks > 44 && $marks <= 49){
                $grade = 'C';
            }else if($marks > 49 && $marks <= 54){
                $grade = 'C+';
            }else if($marks > 54 && $marks <= 59){
                $grade = 'B-';
            }else if($marks > 59 && $marks <= 64){
                $grade = 'B';
            }else if($marks > 64 && $marks <= 69){
                $grade = 'B+';
            }else if($marks > 69 && $marks <= 79){
                $grade = 'A-';
            }else if($marks > 79 && $marks <= 100){
                $grade = 'A';
            }

        $query_details = mysql_query(
        "SELECT staff.staff_id, students.student_id, subjects.subject_id  
        FROM staff, students, subjects 
        WHERE staff.id_number='$tearcher_post_id' 
        AND students.admission_no='$student_no' 
        AND subjects.subject_code='$subject_post_code'")or die(mysql_error());
        $row_details = mysql_fetch_array($query_details);
        $num_details = mysql_num_rows($query_details);

        if($num_details > 0){
            $staff_id= $row_details['staff_id'];
            $student_id= $row_details['student_id'];
            $subject_id= $row_details['subject_id'];

            $query_marks = mysql_query("SELECT * 
            FROM marks 
            WHERE student_id='$student_id'
            AND year_id='$year_id' 
            AND exam_type_id='$exam_id' 
            AND subject_id='$subject_id'")or die(mysql_error());
            $num_marks = mysql_num_rows($query_marks);

        if($num_marks > 0){
            echo 'marks_excist';

        }else{
            $query = mysql_query("INSERT 
            INTO marks 
            (student_id, 
            staff_id,
            term_id,
            year_id,
            exam_type_id,
            subject_id,
            class_id,
            marks)
            values(
            '$student_id', 
            '$staff_id',
            '$term_id',
            '$year_id',
            '$exam_id',
            '$subject_id',
            '$class_id',
            '$marks' )")or die(mysql_error());

            if($query){
                        $query_results = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                        FROM results 
                        WHERE student_id='$student_id' 
                        AND term_id='$term_id' 
                        AND year_id='$year_id' 
                        AND subject_id='$subject_id'")or die(mysql_error());
                        $row_results = mysql_fetch_array($query_results);
                        $num_results = mysql_num_rows($query_results);

                            if($num_results > 0){
                            $id= $row_results['result_id'];
                            $results = $row_results['results'];
                            $total = $results + $marks;
                            $grade = '';
                            if($total >=0 && $total<= 19){
                                    $grade = 'E';
                                }else if($total > 19 && $total <= 29){
                                    $grade = 'D-';
                                }else if($total > 29 && $total <=34){
                                    $grade = 'D';
                                }else if($total > 34 && $total <=39){
                                    $grade = 'D+';
                                }else if($total > 39 && $total <=44){
                                    $grade = 'C-';
                                }else if($total > 44 && $total <= 49){
                                    $grade = 'C';
                                }else if($total > 49 && $total <= 54){
                                    $grade = 'C+';
                                }else if($total > 54 && $total <= 59){
                                    $grade = 'B-';
                                }else if($total > 59 && $total <= 64){
                                    $grade = 'B';
                                }else if($total > 64 && $total <= 69){
                                    $grade = 'B+';
                                }else if($total > 69 && $total <= 79){
                                    $grade = 'A-';
                                }else if($total > 79 && $total <= 100){
                                    $grade = 'A';
                                }




                            mysql_query("UPDATE results 
                            SET results = '$total' AND grade = '$grade' 
                            WHERE result_id = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
                            echo 'true_marks';
            }else{
                mysql_query("INSERT 
                INTO results 
                (student_id, 
                year_id,
                class_id,
                term_id,
                subject_id,
                results,
                grade)
               values(
               '$student_id', 
               '$year_id',
               '$class_id',
               '$term_id',
               '$subject_id',
               '$marks', 
               '$grade' )")or die(mysql_error());

            }


           }else{
               echo 'false_marks';
           }

         }  

        }else{
            echo 'details_dont_excist';
        }




?>
```

Comment: just a tip more than solution - you're going to want to look into switch statements to tidy that long if/else if statement :)

Comment: 80 is an A? <starts rant about "When *I* was in school...">

Comment: Obligatory: Please consider using MySQLi driver for PHP as the MySQL driver has been deprecated for security reasons for quite some time, and is removed in PHP 7. Additionally never trust user input, you should be filtering those request variables..

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but your code is full of SQL Injection vulnerabilities. Please consider using MySQLi or PDO to use prepared statements to help prevent these issues.

Comment: The question as is has low chance of being answered. I suggest improving it by: (i) including the two tables at the top (removing unrelated columns), (ii) giving steps required to get the *faulty* records in the tables, (iii) showing what the records should be had there be no issue, (iv) showing a simplified version of your existing code with unrelated lines removed.